# How to redisplay / recover a deleted text object from a Matlab figure?

Tags: matlab, text, axes, handles, recover

I am now writing a code to display and remove a text object from an axes. However, I do not know the way to redisplay the same text which is deleted. You may understand better by the following codes:

I can add a text to my axes by the following code:
textHandle=text(1,1,'Text')

I also know I can delete the text 'Text' by:
delete(textHandle)

However, how to redisplay the textHandle again at the axes? 
Thank you for your kind attention and help.

Comment: if you used `delete(handle)`, the object is destroyed and no recovery is possible. You have to re-create it (as you created it in the first place). If you do not want to delete it but simply hide it temporarily, then look at the `visible` properties of the [`text`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html?searchHighlight=text) object.

Comment: Thnak you very much Hoki!

Comment: @Hoki Make that comment an answer? It seems good enough

Comment: @LuisMendo. yep, done. Thanks. I developed it a bit to make it more complete. I am still unsure sometimes about what should be an _answer_  and what is just worth a _comment_, mainly in cases like this where the answer is very short or simple.

Comment: @Hoki I am often unsure too. But the comment seemed to be appropriate for the OP and I think it makes a good answer. +1 BTW

Answer (score 1):

if you use `delete(ObjectHandle)`, the object is destroyed and **no recovery is possible**. You just have to re-create it the same way you created it in the first place.

*Note that this apply for a* `text` *object but also for **any** type of Matlab object.*

---

If you do not want to delete it, but simply hide it temporarily until you reuse it, then use the `visible` property of the [`text`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html?searchHighlight=text) object.

For example:

```
set(textHandle,'Visible','off')
```

will simply make the text object invisible. When you want to make it reappear, switch the property back to 'visible' :

```
set(textHandle,'Visible','on')
```

Obviously, this method is only useful if you are sure to reuse your object later on.

Besides the (*very small*) performance gain (not significant for a single text object, but can be useful if many text objects are to be hidden), the main advantage of doing it this way is that **you can still call and modify you text object even when it is hidden**. For example:

```
set(textHandle,'String','New updated text')
```

will execute fine and will display the `'New updated text'` when the visibility of the text object is restored.

*Had you try to set this property after you* **deleted** *the object, Matlab would have just be angry at you and send you back the classic error `??? Error using ==> set / Invalid handle object.`*